# no supported kernel for GPU devices is available for SparseTensorDenseMatMul_grad

Tags: tensorflow

I meet a issue when building a model with **tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul** op in my graph. Part of the error info pasted as below,

Does that mean there is no GPU kernel support to compute the gradient of "**SparseTensorDenseMatMul_grad**"? I can build the model successfully with "**allow_soft_placement=Ture**" in the session config. However, I need all the computation keep on GPU for some special reason. Does anyone know how to fixed this issue? Or I need to implement the CUDA kernel of this op by myself? Thanks a lot.

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device to node 'gradients/softmax_linear/SparseTensorDenseMatMul/SparseTensorDenseMatMul_grad/Slice_1': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
         [[Node: gradients/softmax_linear/SparseTensorDenseMatMul/SparseTensorDenseMatMul_grad/Slice_1 = Slice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT64, _device="/device:GPU:0"](Placeholder_2, gradients/softmax_linear/SparseTensorDenseMatMul/SparseTensorDenseMatMul_grad/Slice_1/begin, gradients/softmax_linear/SparseTensorDenseMatMul/SparseTensorDenseMatMul_grad/Slice_1/size)]]
Caused by op u'gradients/softmax_linear/SparseTensorDenseMatMul/SparseTensorDenseMatMul_grad/Slice_1', defined at:
```